# Different results using $length (field calculator) in QGIS versions 2.18 and 3.0

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, length

I use the field calculator to measure the length of LineStrings in my shapefile layer, but i get different results when using QGIS 2.18 or QGIS 3.0.

If I am using the local coordinate system the difference between the QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.0 is not significant. If I am using WGS84 (I know you should always use the local coordinate system) I get two different results based on the version I am using. In 10 km the difference is almost 2 km..

Does anyone know what might be the reason? Did the algorithm behind the length calculations change in QGIS 3?

Comment: Measuring in EPSG:4326 results in degrees, not meters or kilometers. Does this difference also exist when using a projected crs?

Answer (score 3):

> The built-in functions that use a feature’s geometry (e.g. `$length`) for calculation use the units of the layer’s CRS. Geographic Coordinate Reference System(CRS) such as `EPSG:4326` have degrees as units - so the length of the feature would be in degrees and area in square degrees - which is meaningless. You need to use a Projected Coordinate Reference System with units of meters or feet to perform such calculations.

And the algorithm behind the length calculations probably was not changed.

**QGIS 2.18**

```cpp
 double QgsGeometry::length() const
 {
   if ( !d->geometry )
   {
     return -1.0;
   }
   QgsGeos g( d->geometry );
   return g.length();
 }
```

**QGIS 3.2**

```cpp
 double QgsGeometry::length() const
 {
   if ( !d->geometry )
   {
     return -1.0;
   }
   QgsGeos g( d->geometry.get() );
   mLastError.clear();
   return g.length( &mLastError );
 }
```

---

**References:**

- [Calculating Line Lengths and Statistics](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html)
- [Unit of $length in QGIS Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41580/unit-of-length-in-qgis-field-calculator)
- [QGIS API Documentation  2.18.21-Las Palmas (9fba24a)
  | Line 1297](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/qgsgeometry_8cpp_source.html#l01297)
- [QGIS API Documentation  3.2.0-Bonn (bc43194)
  | Line 1580](https://qgis.org/api/3.2/qgsgeometry_8cpp_source.html#l01580)