# QGIS. Calculate length of lines in temporary draft layer

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, I need to calculate the distance between certain points and save this information as a line shape file, in which the attribute of each element (line) is its length (distance between points).

For this I have created a temporary draft layer of lines to draw the lines and I have obtained this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Now, how do I calculate the lengths and save them as an attribute of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the attribute table of your draft layer of lines and create a new field with the [field calculator](https://geogeek.xyz/basic-operations-with-tables-in-qgis-3.html). Use `$length` or `length ($geometry)` to calculate the length of the lines in your layer. 
Be careful what you measure: "[You need to use a Projected Coordinate Reference System with units of meters or feet to perform such calculations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306050/different-results-using-length-field-calculator-in-qgis-versions-2-18-and-3-0)"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.